# How to access a number field in Cloud Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var totalPointsSideMenu: UILabel!
```

```
 db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid!)
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let totalPoints2 = document.get("totalPoints")
                        self.totalPointsSideMenu?.text = totalPoints2 as? String
                    }
                }
        }
```

and this is what my Firestore cloud looks like:
[image]
I am not getting an error or anything it's just the label shows up blank. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TR;DR - this is how you read an Int from Firestore.

```
let age = doc.get("age") as? Int ?? 0
```

Longer answer: I would suggest a change.

It's not clear why you are querying for a users node by uid. In other words it will simplify things greatly to use the users uid as the documentId

```
users
   uid_0
      totalPoint: 0
      username: "cbaden"
```

then you can access the node directly.

```
let userDoc = collectionRef.document("uid_0")
userDoc.getDocument(completion: { document, error in
    if let err = error {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    guard let doc = document else { return }

    let age = doc.get("age") as? Int ?? 0
    print(age)
})
```

Also note I am using a nil coalescing operator to protect my code. In the case a document doesn't have a 'age' property, doing just this would crash

```
document?.get("age")
```

whereas this

```
document?.get("age") as? Int ?? 0
```

assigned a value of 0 in the case 'age' is missing.